# How to store S3 credentials in environment variables?

Tags: assets, s3

For a Craft 2 S3 asset source, access keys are expected to be entered in from the Control Panel. Is there a way to supply the access key and secret through environment variables instead?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

In Craft 2 [S3 settings](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/assetsourcetypes/S3AssetSourceType.php#L410-L422) ultimately get stored in the database.

Normally the answer would be "you can write a plugin that adds its own Asset Source Type and changes that behavior", but in Craft 2, it is not easy to add custom Asset Source Types, either.

Craft 3 has solved both of those problems.  You can register custom [Asset Volume Types](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/volume-types.md#registering-custom-volume-types) as well as [override Volume settings](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/adf409846292dc7f35f79e0a19dbdc4defd33e20/en/configuration.md#overriding-volume-settings).

Answer (score 1):

You can hack some env-var functionality into your S3 sources by sprinkling `craft()->config->parseEnvironmentString()` into *S3AssetSourceType.php*...

I've historically used this to get per-env *paths* — i.e. parsing vars in `getBaseUrl()`, `getPathPrefix()`, and `getS3Path()` — rather then *credentials*. (I'm usually okay with storing those credentials in the db, because I almost always create an IAM user/policy just for the CMS.)

However, the concept should be the same. Off the top of my head, I think in order to get it to parse credentials and other settings, you'd have to override `getSettings()`, along the lines of:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc BaseSavableComponentType::getSettings()
 *
 * @return BaseModel
 */
public function getSettings()
{

    if (!isset($this->_settings))
    {

        $this->_settings = parent::getSettings();

        foreach ($this->_settings->getAttributes() as $name => $value)
        {
            if (is_string($value))
            {
                $this->_settings->setAttribute(
                    $name,
                    craft()->config->parseEnvironmentString($value)
                );
            }
        }

    }

    return $this->_settings;

}
```

Either you'll need to remember to restore this hack whenever you update Craft, or if you wanted to be super-fancy you could hook onto the `updates.onEndUpdate` event to re-write that method into the correct file.